# URLFetch fails where import doesn't

Tags: warning-messages, web-access, serviceexecute

So as part of breaking down [how to write a service connection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146915/38205) I need to use [`URLFetch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLFetch.html) as opposed to [`URLRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html). Unfortunately this is causing me some headaches as the former throws errors where the latter doesn't.

For instance:

```
In[23]:= URLFetch["https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?\
site=mathematica.stackexchange.com&q=..."]
```

> $CharacterEcoding::utf8
>
> The byte sequence {139} could not be interpreted as a character in 
>   the UTF-8 character encoding.

```
In[26]:= "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?site=\
mathematica.stackexchange.com&q=..." // Import

Out[26]= "{\"items\":[],\"has_more\":false,\"quota_max\":300,\"quota_\
remaining\":260}"
```

How does one get around this?

Comment: It turns out this is exactly the issue encountered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/urlfetch-functionality-for-a-persian-website?rq=1). I'm gonna leave this question up just as a re-route, in case someone else encounters a similar issue.